# Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 package failed - Blocking setup error 0x80044000

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I am trying to install Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 on Windows 10. First it could not install NuGet and other packages due to insufficient write acces to the ProgramData folder (even though I ran the installer as Admin). I solved this by taking ownership of the ProgramData folders.

However, one error remains when installing Update 2:

```
[19E0:19D0][2016-05-28T13:32:45]i301: Applying execute package:     vsupdate_kb3022398, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\0C0BA25532B60992E90C3255D09E004746C9CB2E\packages\vsupdate_kb3022398\vsupdate_kb3022398.exe, arguments: '"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\0C0BA25532B60992E90C3255D09E004746C9CB2E\packages\vsupdate_kb3022398\vsupdate_kb3022398.exe" /q /norestart /DisableSystemRestore /chainingpackage vs_community_enu_slip /CEIPconsent  /log "D:\Temp_Files\TMP\dd_vs_community_20160528132255_129_vsupdate_kb3022398.log" /OriginalSource "D:\Temp_Files\TMP\{B95F54CF-62F8-4668-AC15-16509EAC5129}\vs_community.exe" /OriginalDisplayMode "Full" -burn.ancestors={04fa3a35-1f49-4510-8051-819cdc1e6e01}'
[19E0:19D0][2016-05-28T13:32:52]e000: Error 0x80044000: Process returned error: 0x80044000
[19E0:19D0][2016-05-28T13:32:52]e000: Error 0x80044000: Failed to execute EXE package.
[1A68:1650][2016-05-28T13:32:52]e000: Error 0x80044000: Failed to configure per-machine EXE package.
```

Download the full error log [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=78611585762266672039).

I have also tried the 'solution' offered in [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b968607a-d1ae-4fa3-888d-af5d036a755e/visual-studio-2013-update-2-package-failed?forum=vssetup) thread.

Any help would be appreciated. Also, when one would know why the installer didn't have access to the programdata folder please enlighten me.

Comment: Try installing .net framework 4.5 before running the update.

Comment: .net 4.5 (and others) are already installed.